# apcompat_v7 when you create a new Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse add automatically this folder `appcompat_v7` when we create a new Android App project, so why this folder is added automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This Android's Support Library is automatically added to support the
>   large diversity of OS devices and the fragmentation that exists
>   between the different versions of Android.

Using the Support library helps to avoid a lot o validations in code related to methods that are not supported in some Android Operative Systems.